# Parameters estimation of ODE system

Tags: estimation, matlab, parameterization

I have all the data and an ODE system of three equations which has 9 unknown coefficients (a1, a2,..., a9).

```
dS/dt = a1*S+a2*D+a3*F
dD/dt = a4*S+a5*D+a6*F
dF/dt = a7*S+a8*D+a9*F

t = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11] 
S = [17110 18045 19898 22069 23621 24414 24294 24433 24302 23107 22074 21162]
D = [1157.33 1231.92 1248.94 1188.33 1268.95 1215.5 1298.84 1302.99 1235.16 1210.36 1535.1 1541.52]
F = [104181 104790 112092 123490 140048 149941 172326 194574 227427 219278 215672 242864]
```

How to find these coefficients (a1,..., a9) of an ODE using for example Matlab?

Comment: To those voting to close: if this were a pure Matlab question we would ship it off to SO in a moment.  But before you can write that Matlab code, it seems to me you have a rather difficult statistical question to answer first! Exactly how do you go about fitting a model to a set of data when that model is given only implicitly in terms of differential equations and not explicitly as a parameterized set of functions?

Comment: @whuber Perhaps the OP could edit the question to more clearly refer to the difficult statistical question rather than the 'how do I make Matlab do this' question; then there could be no doubt where it belongs. In any case, I'll wait.

Comment: @Glen_b I have just done that.

Comment: by inserting 'for example'?

Comment: Because I don't think calculating by hand would be powerful having a lot of mathematical tools. I found a tool which can help in this situation "PottersWheel", but can't download it because an author hasn't sent a download link yet. So I am looking for some similar tools online or some code for estimating parameters of ODE system.

Comment: There exists a number of ways one can go about this. Do you want a frequentist method or a Bayesian method?